# AngularJS + Testacular / Jasmine unit tests: Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to write unit tests for an AngularJS project. The project is based on angular-seed and uses Testacular to run tests. Every attempt to run test.sh script always ends up with "Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS".

I tried this super-simple "test":

```
describe('Testing Jasmine', function() {
  console.log('describe');
  var test = 'test';

  it('should be test', function() {
    console.log('it');
    expect(test).toEqual('test');
  });
});
```

The result is that only 'describe' is logged, the 'it' part is skipped. When I try the same thing on clean angular-seed clone everything works - so I assume that the testing system itself with Testacular and Jasmine is working correctly.
Our project is based on Rails, but the clean angular-seed that I was testing for comparison is running on Apache so I thought that this might be the difference - messed up paths or something in that Rails project.

But there are no error messages, e2e tests work... and also I assume that if some files were missing or paths were incorrect it would not be able to log that 'describe' in tests - if I understand correctly this means that Jasmine is processing the right file (there are no other dependencies in this pseudo-test). How is it possible that the 'describe' part works just fine and only 'it' part seems to be skipped?

Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to re-use the same configuration for both e2e tests and unit tests ? If so, create a separate config for e2e and unit tests. That's exactly how it's described in angular-phonecat tutorial. Check out https://github.com/vojtajina/testacular/issues/66

Answer (score 6):

If you are doing unit tests, do not include the angular-scenario.js file in your testacular config file. That will break the unit tests.

Comment: Bingo. The angular-seed repo includes 'app/lib/angular/angular-*.js' in testacular.conf.js -- and removing that line fixes my issue.

Comment: Or add: 
exclude = ['assets/js/lib/angular-scenario.js'];

Answer (score 2):

e2e testing in testacular has a long way to go. I struggled with this for a while. It turns out that the left side of an expect must be one of the methods defined in the angular documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing.

the following is an example

```
describe('Testing Jasmine', function() {

  it('should be test', function() {
    expect(element('foo').count()).toEqual(1);
  });

});
```

Remember, if you dont enter in one of the prescribed method calls into the expect, testacular will not run the 'it'

Answer (score 1):

Please check the order of the Javascript files.

A similar issue was reported in Testacular and [reordering the js files fixed the problem](https://github.com/vojtajina/testacular/issues/66#issuecomment-9535599).

Comment: I am not sure why this answer was downvoted.  I had the exact same symptoms and I was able to resolve it by looking at the load order of the javascript files (in my testacular config file)

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that you have one of these attributes used on page you are testing:

```
'ng:app', 'ng-app', 'x-ng-app', 'data-ng-app'
```

Because if function `angularInit()` won't find element with one of these arguments runner won't start.

This is espcially important if you would like to use angular test runner on webage that does not have ng-app - with current version it just won't work.